# Percussion Rhythm Help

Tags: rhythm, beginner, percussion

[image]

Hey, so I need help counting the two measures underlined in red (43-44). I play the conga for this and I need help with counting the rhythm here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Supposing the time signature is 4/4 (common time), the rhythm you have underlined sounds like this (where a beat in **bold** means a note you hit).

1 & **2** & 3 **&** 4 **&** | 1 & **2** & 3 & **4 &**

Yes, I know it is an irregular beat but is probably typical of the conga music you play. Do let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: The bold symbols hard barely distinguishable from the non-bold ones sadly :(

Answer (score 4):

Consider each punctuation mark an 8th note and accent the exclamations:

. . ! . . ! . !

. . ! . . . ! !

Alternatively, speak the phrase with each word on an 8th note, accentuating every word which sounds like "TWO", "TOO", etc.  If you can repeat this phrase and snap on each "TWO/TOO/TO/TU" syllable, you should be able to internalize the beat.  Then when you play the piece, you'll be thinking about your mother's tutu.

After TWO is far TOO late TO

Step in-TO my mother's TU-TU.

This phrase will haunt you for the rest of your life and you will likely be hearing it around your time of death.  I hope that it was worth this to learn these two measures properly.  You're welcome.

Comment: This is a great way to remember a particular phrase. If finding homophones is too (!) time-consuming, just come up with an ordinary sentence that has the same emphases. +1

Comment: Some of us are TOO compelled by our homophonic tendencies.

Comment: Trouble is, there aren't that many homophones with more than two spellings/meanings, which is where my comment came in.